# IPTV receiving channels and their retransmission

Tags: networking, iptv

I am new in the field of IPTV. I want to get channels from a certain server, i have the protocol the receiver can connect to this server through.
which means i have its host name and port.
and i have xml files which have the following inside them:

```
<root>
    <category>
    <category name="Arabic قنوات عربية">
    <movie name="MBC 1"    link="http://xtreamip.dynns.com:9000/live/iippdd/5sdgFSDdsg/1480.ts"` 
 picture="http://178.62.220.69/pic/mbc1.jpg"/>
    </category>
    </category>
    </root>
```

i am not sure if these files are the same as .M3U files, the ones used to play channels in VLC player.
i would like to ask how am i supposed to get channels in order to be able to retransmit them to many other people using set top boxes?

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to understand if the content owner allows transmission without any cost/fee, first.

Common sense usually applies here - if it is a commercial program or channel the chances are very high that you can't legally just retransmit it. In fact you may find the content is protected with DRM, anyway.

Assuming you have a channel which you are allowed to retransmit, then if your STB's are IP enabled you could simply use the original URL for the movie/channel if that works in the target region.

If your target STB's are cable or satellite then you need a much more involved solution with a proper cable/satalite headend and infrastructure.